# getting "SyntaxError:" Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse"

Tags: json, angular, spring-boot, angular7, gzip

getting "SyntaxError:" Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse"  on fetching data from backend spring boot compressed as gzip in Angular 7

In backend I'm compressing the list of objects as follows:

**ArticleObj.java**

```
public class ArticleObj{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String heading;
    private String language;
    private String identifier1;
    private String identifier2;
    private String identifier3;
    private String identifier4;
    private String identifier5;
    private String identifier6;
    private String identifier7;
    private String identifier8;
    private String identifier9;
    private String identifier10;
    private String baseIndentifier;
    private String moduleId;
    .....
    ...
}
```

// size of the list is around 5000-6000

```
 List<ArticleObj> tempList=new ArrayList<ArticleObj>();
    
    String json=new Gson().toJson(tempList);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);    
    gzip.write(json.getBytes());
    gzip.close();
    String outStr = out.toString("UTF-8");
```

In Angular, I'm this is what I'm trying

```
getData(){
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip", "Content-Type":"application/json"
    })
return this.http.get(url,{headers:headers});
}

this.getData().subscribe(res=> ....)
```

I don't know how to decompress the gzip data into json in angular. The reason I'm compressing the list into gzip is because the size of the list is more than 20mb and is taking lot of time in angular to consume that data. Can anyone please help me our here.

Comment: Please add the content of tempList and the complete stack trace.

Comment: @Milgo, I've updated the details, please have a look

Comment: You still miss the stack trace. Think also about using pagination.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending a zip file from the back-end you should send the JSON and use [gzip compression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding). Browsers have built-in support for gzip compressed HTTP responses and will automatically unzip the contents. In this way you won't have to handle unzipping yourself and you can just use the JSON body.

Keep in mind that gzip will speed up the time spent to download the resource but will take additional CPU resources to decompress the archive.

Comment: @Tsvetav Ganev  If I'm sending response as JSON, then please let me know when and where I'm suppose to use gzip compression?

Comment: You have to find a way to enable it in Spring but I'm pretty sure it is supported. Maybe it's just a matter of configuration.

Answer (score 0):

@Tsvetav Ganev, thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. I did what you said and sent my response as JSON and implemented spring boot gzip compression using

```
server.compression.enabled=true 
server.compression.mime-types=application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/javascript,text/css
server.compression.min-response-size=2KB (2kb is default min size)
```

in application.properties file.

Now the response time is almost 80% reduced.